# Quicksort implementation correctness

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Is there any case where this implementation might fail? I understand that it might run very slowly for some cases, but the my worry for now is more about correctness

```
class QuickSort {
public int findpivot(int []nums, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = nums[start];
    int left = start+1;
    int right = end;
    while(left<=right) {
        while(left<=right && nums[left]<=pivot)
            left++;
        while(left<=right && nums[right]>pivot)
            right--;
        if(left<right) {
            var tmp = nums[left];
            nums[left] = nums[right];
            nums[right] = tmp;
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    int tmp = nums[right];
    nums[right] = nums[start];
    nums[start] = tmp;
    return right;
}
public void sort(int []nums, int start, int end) {
    if(start<end) {
        int pivot = findpivot(nums, start, end);
        sort(nums,start,pivot-1);
        sort(nums,pivot+1,end);
    }
}
public int[] sortArray(int[] nums) {
   sort(nums,0,nums.length-1);
   return nums;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are cases where it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, could you provide counter example input?

Comment: Have you tested it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation correctly sorts arrays.

It is a mix of ideas from [Hoare's and Lomuto's algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort):

- The pivot value's location is excluded from the range that is iterated, and after the loop completes, it is swapped into position -- between the partitions -- so that the function can return the index that separates the two partitions **and** which has the pivot value. That means the caller can exclude this index from recursive calls. This is a principle that is used by Lomuto's algorithm.
- The loop uses two indices that approach each other from both ends of the loop's range, ensuring that the values that are outside of this shrinking window are located in the correct partition: this implements Hoare's algorithm.

Some worry could arise about the last swap, because `left` and `right` could either be equal or could have overtaken each other. First of all, we can be sure the outer loop executes at least once, because the `findPivot` function is only called when `start<end`. When the loop ends, we can be sure that `right` is a valid index, i.e. we have `start<=right<=end`. We can also be sure `nums[right]<=pivot` because either `right==start` (and `nums[start]==pivot`) or `right` is an index that was already processed with `left`. Therefore the final swap will move that value to the correct partition.

With these observations we can say the algorithm will correctly sort an array.

One of the things to do to ensure the code is correct, is to stress test it with random input of differing sizes.

Here is some code that does that:

```java
    for (int size = 0; size < 50; size++) {
        System.out.println("Testing with arrays of size " + size);    
        int[] nums = new int[size];
        // Make array list with sorted values
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            lst.add(i);
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
            // Shuffle
            Collections.shuffle(lst);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                nums[i] = lst.get(i);
            }
            qs.sortArray(nums);
            // Verify
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (nums[i] != i) System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Tests completed");
```

Comment: Thankks @trinkcot for the tips. Are you saying my algo though might be slower but is correct based on what you wrote?

Comment: In practice Hoare's algorithm runs slightly faster, because if it gets to a partition that happens to be sorted, it will not perform any swaps. Your algorithm will always perform at least one swap. Secondly, choosing the first element as pivot will lead to a worst case time complexity when the input list is already sorted. It is better to choose a random pivot. Hoare's algorithm can easily take a random pivot.